# Farbric js: Text active object of canvas not able to edit after adding event listener in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, event-handling, fabricjs

After adding event listener for copy paste, cut paste and moving left right top down functionality when i added the new text on canvas i am not able to edit the active object Text. i am using this [fabricjs-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabricjs-react) module.

This is the code for event listener for above functionality

```
  ...
  const { editor, onReady } = useFabricJSEditor();
  useEffect(() => {
        if (!editor || !fabric) {
            return;
        }
        const handleKeyDown = (event: any) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const code = event.which || event.keyCode;
            let charCode = String.fromCharCode(code).toLowerCase();
            if (code === 37) {
                moveSelected([-1, 0], editor);
            } else if (code === 38) {
                moveSelected([0, -1], editor);
            } else if (code === 39) {
                moveSelected([1, 0], editor);
            } else if (code === 40) {
                moveSelected([0, 1], editor);
            }
            else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && charCode === 'x') {
                copy(editor)
                removeSelectedObject(editor)
            } else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && charCode === 'c') {
                copy(editor)
            } else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && charCode === 'v') {
                paste(editor)
            } else {
            }
    };
    editor?.canvas.renderAll();
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
}, [editor]);
    ...
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1 className="mt-5">Canvas Testing</h1>
            <ToolBar editor={editor} a={posa} b={posb} cref={cref} fabric={fabric} cropImage={cropImage} setColor={setColor} setBImage={setBImage} setBColor={setBColor} bcolor={bcolor} cbcolor={cbcolor} color={color} />
            <div
                ref={cref} className="flex justify-center items-center border-2 border-gray-950 overflow-scroll m-7"
            >
                <FabricJSCanvas className="sample-canvas" onReady={onReady} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Tried adding this in `useEffect` but not able to make it work

```
 ...
  const handleKeyUp = (e: any) => {
            if (e.keyCode == 46) {
                console.log("key.. event up ")
                var obj: any = editor?.canvas.getActiveObject();
                if (!obj.isEditing) {
                    editor?.canvas.remove(obj);
                }
            }
        }
  editor?.canvas.renderAll();
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  ...
```

Please suggest me to make it editable text on canvas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i managed to make it works using the code reference from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tg_alfa/1nyuzkhy/) and changed the code in `useEffect` like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor || !fabric) {
      return;
    }
    const onKeyDownHandler= (event: any)=> {
      //event.preventDefault();
      var key;
      if(window.event){
          key = window.event.keyCode;
      }
      else{
          key = event.keyCode;
      }
      switch(key){
          // Shortcuts
          case 67: // Ctrl+C
                  if(event.ctrlKey){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      copy(editor);
                  }
              break;
          // Paste (Ctrl+V)
          case 86: // Ctrl+V
                  if(event.ctrlKey){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      paste(editor);
                  }
              break;
          case 37:
            event.preventDefault();
            moveSelected([-1, 0], editor);
            break;
          case 38:
            event.preventDefault();
            moveSelected([0, -1], editor);
            break;
          case 39:
            event.preventDefault();
            moveSelected([1, 0], editor);
            break;
          case 40:
            event.preventDefault();
            moveSelected([0, 1], editor);
            break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  }
  editor?.canvas.renderAll();
  document.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;
  }, [editor]);
```